# Find nearest three values of a number from an array of numbers

Tags: c++, arrays

I have 20 coorinates `x[20], y[20]`, I'm trying to get the nearest 3 coorinates to the user coordinate, this function supposed to return the indexes of the 3 nearest values.

```
    double distanceFormula(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2){
        return sqrt(pow((x1 - x2), 2) + pow((y1 - y2), 2));
    }

    int* FindNearestThree(double keyX, double keyY, double x[], double y[]){
    int wanted [3];
    double distance;
    double distTemp;
    for (int i = 0; i<20; i++)
    {
        distTemp = formula(keyX, x[i], keyY, y[i]);
        if (distance != null || distance > distTemp){
            distance = distTemp;
            wanted[0] = i;
        }
        //this will get only the nearest value
    }
    return results;
    }
```

Comment: You will need to compute the 2D distance between all points, then sort by that distance, picking off the first 3.

Comment: There are a number of errors in your code, as well as in your algorithm.  Can you give a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) illustrating the problem?

Comment: @Jason I currently writing this on a code editor, I'm just drawing it.

Comment: If it's just 20 points, then just calculate the distances of every point and sort.  If you have a _lot_ of points, then check out the [k-nearest neighbors algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using Point = std::pair<int, int>;
std::array<Point, 20> points;
populate(points);
std::sort(
    points.begin()
  , points.end()
  , [up=get_user_coords()](const Point& p1, const Point& p2) {
        int d1 = std::pow(up.first - p1.first, 2) + std::pow(up.second - p1.second, 2);
        int d2 = std::pow(up.first - p2.first, 2) + std::pow(up.second - p2.second, 2);
        return d1 < d2;
    });
// The nearest 3 points are now at indices 0, 1, 2.
```

If you need to work with *many, many more* points, then I suggest doing some research on the [Nearest neighbor search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search), because this can get slow fast.

Answer (score 0):

i guess it might be the simplest and really ugly solution:

```
for (int j = 0; j <3; j++) {
  for (int i = 0; i<20; i++)
    { /* if statement needed here to check if you already 
      have current value in your result set
      and then your loop as it is*/
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Comment: who wants an ugly solution! there's another way to write a code in Stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: thanks Murhaf. Well in fact it's on the level of code from question.

Answer (score 0):

Following may help:

```
template <std::size_t N, typename It, typename Queue>
std::array<It, N> asArray(Queue& queue, It emptyValue)
{
    std::array<It, N> res;
    for (auto& e : res) {
        if (queue.empty()) {
            e = emptyValue;
        } else {
            e = queue.top();
            queue.pop();
        }
    }
    return res;
}

template <std::size_t N, typename It, typename ValueGetter>
std::array<It, N>
MinNElementsBy(It begin, It end, ValueGetter valueGetter)
{
    auto myComp = [&](const It& lhs, const It& rhs)
    {
        return valueGetter(*lhs) <  valueGetter(*rhs);
    };
    std::priority_queue<It, std::vector<It>, decltype(myComp)> queue(myComp);

    for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        queue.push(it);
        if (N < queue.size()) {
            queue.pop();
        }
    }
    return asArray<N>(queue, end);
}
```

[Live Demo](http://ideone.com/CrOkgJ)